# Use a single Layout page across multiple asp.net core projects

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, virtual

I work for a company that develops many websites to be used internally but many have parts that are public facing. It is important that all our sites look the same. In moving to dotnet core we found that we are no longer able to use a virtual directory to host the Layout page for our site.

We were storing our Layout page on a file share and referencing it in our projects with a virtual directory. This way if we needed to change the information in the footer, header, or some style/js we could upload a single change to the Layout page and that change would take place on all our sites.

I've tried researching any possible ways and the only thing I can come up with is a custom middleware that downloads the layout page from the file share and updates the current layout page if it is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core gives you the capability of creating [Razor libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). This would be a separate project where you can have shared views and reference it to the rest of your projects. You can find a [simple implementation here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/razor-pages/ui-class/samples/cli).

You can choose **one** of these two options to do this.

1. Reference this project in each solution. Since your solutions directly reference the razor library, any change that is made in the common library will be reflected in every solution without the need of repacking and publish.
2. use `dotnet pack` to create a nuget in a shared location. While this option will require you to repack and publish each time, in some cases it would be a more organized solution. You can have a version setup. This means that when you update the shared razor project you will define a new version number. You can update this on each one of your solutions. This reduces the risk of a project breaking. Let's say you have 5 projects and 2 of them are not compatible with the latest update. In this case, you can update the 3 right away. The remaining 2 can be updated when you can spend time updating these projects to match the new requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that would be able to be updated without having to update libraries and republish for every project.

Comment: You shouldn't have to republish. you can just reference this project in all of your solutions.

Comment: From my understanding of libraries and Nuget packages after updating the Nuget package/razor library I would then have to go into each project that references that library, update the package, and then republish to get the changes made. Am I incorrect?

Comment: I have pointed out two options. What you said is true for the second option. If you use the first option which is referencing the library, you will not have to update anything. Your changes will be directly reflected in all solutions

Comment: I just updated my question. i am sure option 1 will serve your needs. I just provided a second option for others.

Comment: The first option does require to republish the website every time.  What you're suggesting is just several solutions targeting the same project, but each solution would still need to be recompiled.

Comment: Use Razor Class Library ...